# How to debug warden/devise because it's ignoring a cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, warden

I used SAML strategy for devise (https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable).

I did some modifications to it and I see that if a user isn't authenticated it goes and authenticate a user and I log that `sucess!()` called. As result, browser is getting a session cookie.

The browser coming back to my website with this session cookie. However, warden requires to authenticate again (leading to never ending authentication loop) instead of just letting this user through.

My question is: How can I debug it to see why warden calls authentication (vs just letting it through).

I added before_action to ApplicationController and did `puts request.env`. I see that session cookie is coming. However, I am not sure what should be the next step to check what's going on.